# How to define www.*.abc.example.com wildcard domain in nginx server block?

Tags: nginx, web-server

I want to define my own domain something like this - www.*.abc.example.com in nginx server blocks . i have tried to do like this - www(.*).abc.example.com * & it throws error like - nginx: [emerg] invalid server name or wildcard "www(.*).abc.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:443

Comment: `server_name ~ ^www\..*\.abc\.example\.com$;`

Comment: @IvanShatsky i am getting error - nginx: [emerg] empty regex in server name "~" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ now after adding the above content .

Comment: Yep... there should be no space between the `~` and the regex pattern: `server_name ~^www\..*\.abc\.example\.com$;`

Comment: thanks it worked , however now i am getting another issue -

Comment: thanks @IvanShatsky it worked , however i am getting the following ssl error - This server could not prove that it is www.abc.example.com ; its security certificate is from *.abc.example.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.  Please let me know how to fix the issue . and i am using amazon acm manager to get a certificate for my website . which i had requested only for *.abc.example.com earlier , But how to request a new certificate for the www domain as well ?

Comment: Certificate issued for `*.abc.example.com` should work for `www.abc.example.com`. I know nothing about amazon acm manager (as well as about any other amazon services). The only thing I ever used to get a wildcard certificate is the [ACME Shell script](https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh) in the [DNS manual mode](https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh/wiki/DNS-manual-mode).

Comment: thanks for your recommendations , i will check the scme shell script .